# Best way to ignore null values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My data looks like this,

[image]

I have multiple values in the *Table* field with each having its own unique values for the *Data* field. However, *Data* values for TableA will be the same format in the table *myTable*. Same applies to all records in the *Table* field.

I am using `JSON_EXTRACT` to get the value in conjunction with `CASE` statements.

```
SELECT
 CASE
        WHEN
            Table = 'table A'
        THEN
            CONCAT_WS('\n','Name: ',
                    JSON_EXTRACT(Data, '$.name'))
    END AS 'tableA',
CASE
        WHEN
            Table = 'table B'
        THEN
            CONCAT_WS('\n','Location: ',
                    JSON_EXTRACT(Data, '$.fieldType'))
    END AS 'tableB' from myTable
```

The problem with this is that I will be getting *null* values.

I am getting the below results,

[image]

I am expecting the below results,

[image]

I want to avoid the null values. Is there any other way to extract the data ?  I am using **MYSQL**.

Comment: Null values as in where ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 as in, if tableA is not encountered it will show tableA field as null, which is as expected. I want to know if there an alternate way of extracting the data by avoiding nulls

Comment: If I understood you, isn't it just to add "where Table is not null" ?

Comment: Show example of the results you get now and show example of the results you want.

Comment: @VBoka I have edited my question. I hope it is clear now

Comment: @Ayubx  now how do you want results to look like ? Explain why also... avoid null can mean  to put something instead of null's, also it can mean you want one row or maybe two rows and one column. Also, add the expected results in a form of a text not an image

Comment: @VBoka I want the sql to show tableA results if tableA is found and not show tableB. As I understand it the case statement is functioning as normal. I want to know if there is a better way to extract the data based on the info i have provided

Comment: @Ayubx - I have posted my solution. Kindly check

Comment: @Ayubx please just show what results do you expect to get.

Comment: @VBoka I have added the expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option one:

```
Select * 
from ( SELECT CASE WHEN Table_c = 'table A' THEN
                        CONCAT_WS('\n','Name: ', JSON_EXTRACT(data_c, '$.name'))
              END AS 'TableA'
       from test_t) A,
     ( SELECT CASE WHEN Table_c = 'table B' THEN
                        CONCAT_WS('\n','Location: ', JSON_EXTRACT(data_c, '$.fieldType'))
              END AS 'TableB'
       from test_t) B
where TableA is not null 
and TableB is not null
```

Option two:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Table_c = 'table B' THEN
                 CONCAT_WS('\n','Location: ', JSON_EXTRACT(data_c, '$.fieldType'))
            ELSE
                 CONCAT_WS('\n','Name: ', JSON_EXTRACT(data_c, '$.name'))
       END AS 'Data'
       , CASE WHEN Table_c = 'table B' THEN
                 'Table B'
            ELSE
                 'Table A'
         END AS 'Table'
from test_t
```

[Here is the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=334e5c4c39d75951b91ce698f92db88a)

Please note that I have changed the names of the table and columns in my demo.

Comment: Thank you. I am testing option 1 but I am still getting nulls. I am checking why atm. Am sure you understand I do have more than the two rows I have provided in the example.Other rows with differing tables(Table field) but as mentioned earlier one table having the same format for the data field throught the table.

Answer (score 0):

Note: you have to understand these are not actual null values in database but because your requirement is to read and convert the rows to columns and thus each row in the final result will have null value for all columns other than the corresponding derived one. We can use max on each column (each "CASE" as in your query).

You could try with below,

```
SELECT MAX(IF(data_type = 'TableA', CONCAT_WS('\n', 'Name: ', 
                                           JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.name')) 
           , '')) 
       TableA, 
       MAX(IF(data_type = 'TableB', CONCAT_WS('\n', 'Location: ', 
                                        JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.fieldType')), '')) 
       TableB 
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Table = 'table A'
                THEN CONCAT_WS('\n', 'Name: ', JSON_EXTRACT(Data, '$.name'))
           END) AS tableA,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Table = 'table B'
                THEN CONCAT_WS('\n','Location: ', JSON_EXTRACT(Data, '$.fieldType'))
           END) AS tableB
from myTable;
```

If there could be multiple matches in the JSON, then you might want `GROUP_CONCAT()` instead:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Table = 'table A'
                         THEN CONCAT_WS('\n', 'Name: ', JSON_EXTRACT(Data, '$.name'))
                    END) AS tableA,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Table = 'table B'
                         THEN CONCAT_WS('\n','Location: ', JSON_EXTRACT(Data, '$.fieldType'))
                    END) AS tableB
from myTable;
```